# How can I compact my x86 bootloader code?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

I know that this may be asking too much, but i'm writing a pong game in a bootloader file, but I seem to have run out of space to add in any more code. I've tried to compress my code into the 512 byte file, but I can't find any other ways to compress it even more.

Here's the code (I'm quite new, so it may not be very good):

```
[BITS 16]               ; so NASM knows that i'm working in 16 bit mode

_start:
    mov ah, 0x00            ; loads the settings which, instead of printing, clear the screen
    mov al, 0x03
    int 10h                 ; BIOS text opcode (i think)

    mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set data segment to where we're loaded
    mov ds, ax
        
    mov ECX, 80             ; loop for the top line to save space
    call topbottomlinefunc

    mov ah, 01h
    int 16h

    jz .stop1       ; runs through the keyboard buffer and removes any key presses that aren't w, s, up and down, so they don't clog up the movement
    cmp ah, 11h     
    je .stop1
    cmp ah, 1fh
    je .stop1
    cmp ah, 48h
    je .stop1
    cmp ah, 50h
    je .stop1

    mov ah, 00h
    int 16h

    .stop1:

    mov dl, 11h     ; <-- al is which  key to searach for
    lea bx, pos1    ; <-- eax is the memory address of the paddle which is having the position updated
    mov cl, 02h     ; <-- cl is what should be added
    mov ch, 00h     ; <-- ch is what should be subtracted (i can't use negative numbers)
    call scaninputkey

    mov dl, 1fh     ; above
    mov cl, 00h     ; doesn't need to change the memory address as it was changed in the one before
    mov ch, 02h
    call scaninputkey

    mov dl, 48h
    lea bx, pos2
    mov cl, 02h
    mov ch, 00h
    call scaninputkey

    mov dl, 50h
    mov cl, 00h
    mov ch, 02h
    call scaninputkey

    mov ECX, 23                         ; runs through all the y positions and prints what needs to be there
    l3:
    push ECX

        push ECX
        push EDX
        movzx EDX, byte [pos1]          ; moves the leftmost paddle's position into the extended data register
        call checkdraw                  ; runs the subroutine to draw the paddles
        pop EDX

        mov ECX, 37                     ; runs through half of the x positions and prints what needs to be there
        l1:
            movzx EDX, byte [ballx]     ; moves the ball's x position into the extended data register
            sub EDX, 38                 ; subtracts 38 from the x position, so it goes from right to left (it would be left to right, but 512 bytes isn't enough)
            cmp ECX, EDX                ; compares the current x position to the ball's x positiona dn runs the subroutine to check the y position as well if it is
            je drawball1
            pointer1:                   ; checkpoint for the ball position checking subroutine (bad code)
            mov si, placeholder
            call print_string
            pointer2:                   ; above
        loop l1

        mov si, middleline              ; brings in and draws the middle line
        call print_string

        mov ECX, 37                     ; runs through the other half of the x positions and prints what needs to be there
        l2:
            movzx EDX, byte [ballx]
            cmp ECX, EDX                ; doesn't take away 38 from it so it runs from right to left
            je drawball3
            pointer3:
            mov si, placeholder
            call print_string
            pointer4:
        loop l2

        pop ECX
        push EDX                        ; this is the same as the other one, but with the rightmost paddle, instead of the leftmost one
        movzx EDX, byte [pos2]
        call checkdraw
        pop EDX

    pop ECX
    loop l3

    mov ECX, 79             ; repeats 79 times to fill the screen, without having the bios create a new line
    call topbottomlinefunc

    MOV     CX, 01h         ; 100ms rest, CX and DX are combined into one 24 bit register, i believe it can be increased to a 32 bit register
    MOV     DX, 7d40h
    MOV     AH, 86h         ; changes the operation rigister to rest for CX:DX amount of time
    INT     15h             ; BIOS operation to do with time (i think)

    call moveball

    jmp _start          ; Jump here - infinite loop!

.data:

    balldirx db 00h                     ; declares the initial ball directions
    balldiry db 00h

    pos1 db 05h                         ; declares the initial paddle positions
    pos2 db 0ch

    ballx db 17h                        ; declares the initial ball positions
    bally db 0ah

    player db '##', 00h                 ; declares the text which should be printed for different things:
    middleline db '||', 00h             ; paddles are hashtags, the middle line is 2 pipes, the top and bottom lines are equals signs, the ball is made of percent signs
    placeholder db ' ', 00h
    doubleplaceholder db '  ', 00h
    topline db '=', 00h
    ball db '%', 00h

topbottomlinefunc:
    .l5:
        mov si, topline
        call print_string
    loop .l5

    ret

moveball:                           ; moveballdown and moveballup can also probably be condensed into one subroutine
    cmp byte [bally], 01h           ; compares the register and bottom, if they are the same, it would reverse the ball's velocity
    je .reversebally
    cmp byte [bally], 17h
    je .reversebally

    cmp byte [balldiry], 00h        ; if balldiry is 0, it will move down, else, it will move up
    je .movedown
    jne .moveup

    .moveup:                        ; can be reference in a conditional jump
        inc byte [bally]
        jmp .moveballx
    .movedown:
        dec byte [bally]
        jmp .moveballx

    .reversebally:  
        not byte [balldiry]         ; if balldiry is 0 (down), it will chage to ff (up), and vice versa
        cmp byte [balldiry], 00h
        je .movedown
        jne .moveup

    .moveballx:
        cmp byte [ballx], 01h           ; compares the register and bottom, if they are the same, it would reverse the ball's velocity
        je .reverseballx
        cmp byte [ballx], 4bh
        je .reverseballx

        cmp byte [balldirx], 00h
        je .movedownb
        jne .moveupb

        .moveupb:
            add byte [ballx], 02h
            ret
        .movedownb:
            sub byte [ballx], 02h
            ret

        .reverseballx:
            not byte [balldirx]
            cmp byte [balldirx], 00h
            je .movedownb
            jne .moveupb

drawball1:                      ; drawball 1 and drawball 3 can probably be condensed into one subroutine
    pop EBX                     ; gets the current print y position
    movzx EDX, byte [bally]     ; moves the ball y position into the data register to be compared to te current print position
    cmp EBX, EDX
    push EBX                    ; returns the current print y position so the print isn't stuck in an infinite loop
    je .drawball2
    jmp pointer1                ; return to before the empty character will be printed if the positions don't match up

    .drawball2:
        mov si, ball            ; draws the one by one ball, will be bigger in the future
        call print_string

        jmp pointer2            ; return to after the empty character has been printed

drawball3:
    pop EBX
    movzx EDX, byte [bally]
    cmp EBX, EDX
    push EBX
    je .drawball4
    jmp pointer3

    .drawball4:
        mov si, ball
        call print_string

        jmp pointer4

scaninputkey:

    mov ah, 01h             ; gets the first value in the keyboard buffer
    int 16h

    cmp ah, dl              ; compares the first value in the keyboard buffer to the key specified just before calling this subroutine
    jne .done

    mov ah, 00h             ; removes the key if the first value is the same as the specified key, so it doesn't only use that key
    int 16h

    add byte [bx], cl           ; either doesn't add or subtract properly, or the memory address isn't loaded properly, I would suggest the latter
    sub byte [bx], ch           ; <-- same here
        
    .scankey:               ; removes duplicate keys to the one specified before calling the subroutine

        mov ah, 01h
        int 16h

        jz .done            ; skips searching if the buffer is empty

        cmp ah, dl
        jne .done           ; skips seacrhing if the keys aren't the same

        mov ah, 00h         ; removes the key from the buffer is they are
        int 16h

        jmp .scankey        ; repeats the process to remove more duplicates

    .done:

        ret

checkdraw:              
    cmp ECX, EDX        ; checks if the current y coordinate that is being drawn is equal to the position of the paddle
    je drawplayer       ; draws and finishes the subroutine if they are the same
    dec ECX             ; lowers the y coordinate to check so the paddle becomes wider
    cmp ECX, EDX
    je drawplayer
    dec ECX             ; essentially the same as what I expained before
    cmp ECX, EDX
    je drawplayer
    add ECX, 3
    cmp ECX, EDX
    je drawplayer
    inc ECX
    cmp ECX, EDX
    je drawplayer
    sub ECX, 2
    cmp ECX, EDX
    jne drawblank

drawplayer:
    
    mov si, player              ; draws a hashtag where the paddle should be
    call print_string
    
    ret

drawblank:
    
    mov si, doubleplaceholder   ; doesn't draw a hashtag where the player shouldn't be
    call print_string
    
    ret

print_string:           
    mov ah, 0eh                 ; sets the mode to BIOS scrolling mode (prints the character, then moves the pointer one along to the right)

    .render:
        lodsb                   ; loads the string settings
        cmp al, 0               ; checks if the current character is null, stops printing if it is
        je .done
        int 10h                 ; the opcode to print a character
        jmp .render             ; does the whole thing again, incrementing the pointer by 1 each time

.done:
    ret                         ; returns the the place where the print_string subroutine was called

    times 510-($-$$) db 0   ; Pad remainder of boot sector with 0s, must be total 512 bytes so the BIOS recognises it as a bootloader
    dw 0xaa55       ; The standard PC boot signature
```

here's my compiling and running options (i'm on Ubuntu):

```
nasm boot.asm -f bin -o boot.bin
dd status=noxfer conv=notrunc if=boot.bin of=boot.img
qemu-system-i386 -fda boot.img
```

I would also like to understand how I can do it by myself, so if you're willing, can you message me on discord. My username is: Chromegism

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `mov cl, 02h` / `mov ch, 00h` is two 2-byte instructions.  `mov cx, 0002h` does the same thing in 3 bytes.  If `call scaninputkey` will definitely leave CX unmodified, you only need to do that once, instead of before every call.  (If that's not already guaranteed, you could `push cx` at the top of that function, `pop cx` at the bottom, so the save/restore happens every time, but the instructions appear only twice in your program for only 2 bytes of extra static code size to save 3 more `mov cx, 2` instructions = 6 bytes.)

Comment: I wrote bootloaders that can live within one or two reserved sectors of a FAT file system. In the default protocol they will follow the FAT chains to load less than 24 KiB of a kernel file, then pass control to this initial part with a load protocol that allows the kernel initial loader to load the remainder of itself, enabling binaries even much larger than 64 KiB. Documentation at https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/ldosboot.htm and repo at https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldosboot/

Comment: And never use `lea` to put an address into a register; `mov reg, imm16` is 3 bytes, vs. `lea reg, [disp16]` is 4 bytes since it also needs a ModRM byte.  So `mov bx, pos2`.   Also, since this is 16-bit code, prefer 16-bit operand-size most of the time, for `push` / `sub` / `cmp` etc, or even 8-bit and just use a partial register; the false dependency shouldn't be a significant slowdown since any CPU with out-of-order exec will be very fast.

Comment: For more about writing small x86 machine code, see [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132981) and some of the linked answers such as AnatolyG's 386 DOS [1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58779) , and my [User Appreciation Challenge #1: Dennis ♦](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/123194) (an immediate bitmap for `bt` is a good way of testing for one a few letter of the alphabet, although maybe not for larger ranges like any input key like your case, if you can't range reduce; and a bitmap in memory would need an address.)

Comment: `not byte [balldiry]` / `cmp byte [balldiry], 00h` could be `xor byte [balldiry], -1` to flip it and set FLAGS according to the result. (Unlike NOT, which for some reason doesn't affect FLAGS.  If I recall, Stephen Morse wrote in his book, the 8086 Primer (free on his web site: https://stevemorse.org/8086/), that this was an oversight, not an intentional design decision!).

Comment: After branching one way, don't use the opposite conditional branch.  Either use `jmp`, or better, put the target block of code right after this so you can just fall into it.  e.g. `jne .moveupb` is a no-op, that label is already next so execution goes to the same place whether it's taken or not.  Or in `je .drawball4` / `jmp pointer3` / `.drawball4:`, that could simply be `jne pointer3` with fall-through into .drawball4 for the not-taken case.  (You never need to jcc over a single jmp on 386 or later, since `jcc rel16` is available, unlike on earlier x86 where conditional branches were short)

Comment: There are all just local micro-optimizations.  I haven't tried to look at the whole thing and find ways to get the same results with a more compact algorithm.

Comment: Since we're nit-picking, it seems to me you are pushing/popping `ecx` twice in `l3...` where one would do.

Comment: `topbottomlinefunc` should not use a string, just repeat the character. Makes smaller code and gets rid of the string. `checkdraw` is a mess, if you want to range check then subtract the two values and use a single unsigned comparison. Also if you code it such that `ecx` is not changed you don't have to save and restore in the caller.

Comment: This might perhaps be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, where long answers that pick apart multiple parts of a non-tiny program are normal.  This does just barely fit in 510 bytes, and apparently is a tested and working program?  That's required for CodeReview, so if some of the "more code" you want to add is required for it to work, perhaps do that and test as a `.com` executable.  But if this does work as-is, then you could ask about it there.